# XmlSerialization, Serialize only one Property of a Child Element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

With a model such as ..

```
class Base {
  public Child Child { get; set; }
}
class Child {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // other properties
}
```

I want to do Xml Serialization, but for the `Child` object on `Base`, I only want to serialize the `Id` property. The rest of the `Child` object will be serialized into its own separate file. Is this possible to do without making two sets of models?

Comment: Even if this is possible how you could handle the deserialization for the Base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only serialize `Child` in the context of `Base`, you can mark the other members with `[XmlIgnore]` and they won't appear.

If you need a different layout in different contexts, then you can use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to define the model at runtime, but this isn't trivial. Also, if doing this you ***MUST*** cache and re-use the resulting `XmlSerializer` (there is a ctor that accepts the overrides), or it will leak dynamic assemblies (there is an inbuilt cache for the trivial `typeof(SomeRoot)` serializers, but custom serializers are not automatically cached, and generate an assembly each; assemblies *cannot* be unloaded).

Comment: XmlIgnore isn't an option because I *do* still need the `Child` object to be serializable.

Comment: @Ciel did you see the rest of the post where I explained in quite some detail how you can achieve that on a single model?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had to go out of town for a few days. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the XmlIgnore attribute on all of the other properties. Not sure if that will get the result you're after.